# R.Layout.mylayout is giving the wrong integer - Android

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm making an Android app. It was working fine, I was fiddling around with stuff, editing the layout xml files, when suddenly it started creating the wrong activities whenever an activity was made. for example, if I want to get the stats.xml layout, I try `setContentView(R.layout.stats);`, but that gives me a different page (the one before alphabetically, called signup.xml).

It works if I use `setContentView(R.layout.stats + 1);` but it's pretty worrying to have to do this! Is there some way I can tell the AndroidManifest.xml file to recalculate all the R.layout integers or something? And what might I have done to cause this bug (assuming this isn't a feature!)?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project *(`Project -> Clean ...` in eclipse)*?

Comment: despite of suggested cleaning: do you use libraries? have you restarted eclipse? have you changed your build target?

Comment: I tried cleaning - it changed it, but it's still wrong. It may have changed the transposition though.  @RafaelT I do use libraries in some of my code, but well after the point where it's already gone wrong. I have restarted eclipse. How would I change my build target, what to and what from?

Comment: do these libs have their own resources? They could cause naming conflicts, and have you cleaned every Project depending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean the project or delete the R class manually.

Comment: Ah - it instantly created an identical R.java file, giving the same error. Cleaning also didn't work... *Edit*: I tell a lie! I was fooled by my earlier attempts to try to compensate for the error, adding one to the R.layout.stats integer. Deleting R.java seemed to do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I did not do anything ;-)